# C# List<t>.ForEach(delegate(type t) and how to remove items as the list is iterated through

Tags: c#, list, xna-4.0

This may be considered bad programming, but prior to .net 4, I used to heavily use code similar to this:

```
    enemyList.ForEach(delegate(Enemy e)
    {
        e.Update();
        if (someCondition)
              enemyList.Remove(e);
    });
```

Now, I'm going through an updating some old projects, and there are a *LOT* of code thats going to have to be changed since ForEach was removed.. Now, I do have an extension to allow me to use the ForEach :

```
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        foreach (T item in sequence)
            action(item);
    }
```

I know I can do this:

```
    var index = 0;
    while(index < enemyList.Count)
    {
        if(condition)
            enemyList.RemoveAt(index);
        else
            index++;
    }
```

But some of those would be a pain to rewrite like that.. Is there any way to add that functionality back so that I can iterate through that list, remove the items I need without having to go back and rewrite and edit all of those functions ? I still consider myself a newbie to coding, and I just can't figure this one out.. Any help would be appreciated!

************* *EDIT* ***************

So I guess it boils down to rewriting a lot of code.. I have a lot of code such as this that I just pulled out of a project:

```
            GameplayScreen.gameWorld.shipList.ForEach(delegate(Ship s)
            {
                if (eS.originalShipsID == s.shipID)
                {
                    if (!eS.Alive || eS.health <= 0)
                    {
                        // this one sunk...
                        string log = "0" + s.shipName + " was sunk in battle.. All crew and cargo were lost.";
                        AddLogEntry(log);
                        totalCrewLost += s.currentCrew;
                        GameplayScreen.gameWorld.shipList.Remove(s);
                    }
                }
            });
```

I was just hoping there was a way to not have to rewrite all of that.. So time to update and change the way I code apparently. Thanks!

Comment: To your edit, in what way could you not refactor that to use `RemoveAll`?  Just reture true instead of removing the item, return false at the end, and other than that it can stay the same.  That's a pretty minimal code change.

Comment: I'm not saying I couldnt.. I was looking for a way to not have to go through all of those files and redo all of the code.. but from what it looks like, thats what I have to do.. It is a pretty minimal change, its just many many many many times..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the list's `RemoveAll` method.

You can refactor the code to:

```
enemyList.RemoveAll(enemy => enemy.SomeCondition);
```

Not only is it better than the `while` loop, I'd argue it's quite a bit better than the `Foreach` method.

Comment: Totally forgot about that overload. I've been using an extension I wrote to do that same thing for forever. +1

Comment: If you look more closely we see that e.Update is also called before the remove.

Comment: @vidstige, That's true, but the update alone could be done using a "dumb" foreach extension.

Comment: @vidstige Two options.  1) You can still call `Update` in this code.  Nothing's stopping you. 2) Since it doesn't mutate the list, you could add a `foreach(var e in enemyList)e.Update()` before this code, which I would consider a better practice as it's a mutating operation, and I like to keep side effects out of anonymous methods like this, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: @StevenWestbrook Why use a foreach extension?  Just use the `foreach` keyword.

Comment: @Servy OP's requirement is maintenance of existing code with minimal effort, hence the (otherwise rather strange) usage.

Comment: @Servy I like to keep side effects outside too. That doesn't mean you can change code to do something potentially different causing a bug just to get some cleaner code. In this case for example if I where to move out the e.Update() call to its own iteration, it might to something diffrent as you don't know if the e.Update() call affects the "someCondition" causing the changed code to remove a diffrent set of elements.

Comment: @vidstige Given that it's not an option to just leave the code exactly as it is, some changes will simply need to be made, there is no way around that.  Since the code needs to be changed it's important to understand what it does, if you don't, you'll never know if your refactor is changing any behavior at all, no matter how small the change is.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The only way would be to add the items to remove to another list and then iterate over that list and remove them after the initial iteration.

A better option would be to use a reverse for loop to iterate over the values. You can then safely remove the items during the initial iteration:

```
for (var i = enemyList.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
{
    if(condition) enemyList.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: actually you can do it. I would not recommend it thought. Neither would I recommend your method.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you do it a lot, why not do something like this:

```
public static void RemoveIfTrue<T>(this ICollection<T> list, Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    List<T> itemsToRemove = list.Where(condition).ToList();
    foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
    {
        list.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
myList.RemoveIfTrue(x => YourConditionIsTrue)
```

That way you don't have a bunch of duplication of logic.

Comment: Should be able to switch the parameter from `List<T>` to `ICollection<T>`.  @RussCam the method is careful to not throw due to that: it's looping over a separate list.  I don't see any problem with what he's doing; if there is, could you explain it differently?

Comment: @TimS. good call. I actually meant to use IList, but yeah, ICollection works better

Comment: @TimS - for some reason my eyes missed that line on first glance! Duly noted, will remove comment :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `List<T>`, you can use [`List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)

So there is a built-in thing to do this already.

Even better - the built-in one knows exactly how to avoid problems modifying the collection while iterating over it. And because it has access to the private internals, it's more efficient too.

So, just using the List class itself you can write code like this:

`enemies.RemoveAll(enemy => (enemy.Health <= 0));`

Comment: Now you've just made me curious.

Comment: I was trying to paste some code to add to the discussion to show a real world example of what I was trying to avoid rewriting, but didnt realize how stackoverflow comments worked.. and it just wasn't cooperating..

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with a small tweak.  Here's an example:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IList<T> list, Action<T> action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            action(list[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> vals = new List<string>(new string[] { "a", "bc", "de", "f", "gh", "i", "jk" });

        vals.ToList().ForEach<string>(delegate(string value)
        {
            if (value.Length > 1)
            {
                vals.Remove(value);
            }
        });

        vals.ToList().ForEach<string>(delegate(string value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now, there are a couple of things worth mentioning here: first, normally elements would be skipped.  However, a separate copy of the list is made by calling ToList().  Second, you should be careful to do this only with reference types - i.e. not with primitive types - otherwise you'll remove more than a single element with the `remove` method.

**EDIT**

I'd also like to add that probably any of the posted alternatives are better - but I thought it was interesting that this could be done; it's less performant but probably quicker to chuck into existing code.

Comment: `It looks like a separate copy of the array is made for the extension method.` That's because you call `ToList` before calling your extension method.  If you didn't do that and din't copy the list that is passed to the extension method then you'd be skipping the element just after any one that is removed.